# WLAN Receiver monitor mode

Tags: wifi

This is more of a hardware question.
How does a WLAN receiver manage to demodulate every channel simultaniously.
I could need a brief description about that issue. 
In my imagination it is only possible to demodulate a single carrier.

Several WLAN chips have the possibility to monitor the entire on air traffic on every channel with every subcarrier.
I could not find a description of that monitor mode in standard and anywhere else until now.
thanks!

Comment: There is a form (search it in stack meta or something) for this kind of questions

Answer (score 0):

The answer is. It is no broadband sniffing possible. The WLAN Hardware is only capable of sniffing one WLAN channel.